# Why does twitter API add url at the end of the text

Tags: ruby, twitter, rubygems

When getting tweet information using the twitter API, the returned `text` or `full_text` field has a URL appended at the end of the text. For example:

```
    "full_text": "Just another Extended Tweet with more than 140 characters, generated as a documentation example, showing that [\"truncated\": true] and the presence of an \"extended_tweet\" object with complete text and \"entities\" #documentation #parsingJSON #GeoTagged https://twitter.com/FloodSocial/status/994633657141813248"
```

`https://twitter.com/FloodSocial/status/994633657141813248` is appended at the end(The appended url is acutally a shortened url but stackoverflow does not allow shortened url in the body so I just replace it with the full URL). Why does the API add this and is there a way to get the text without the added URL?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct twitter gem?  using `gem install twitter` and setting up a client [according to the docs](http://according%20to%20the%20docs), you should be able to just get the tweet/status by it's ID. But whatever example you are using doesn't show how you got the full text

```
text = client.status('994633657141813248').text
=>"Just another Extended Tweet with more than 140 characters, generated as a documentation example, showing that https://twitter.com/FloodSocial/status/994633657141813248"
```

The url is truncated as a plain string so not sure what you even do to get the string you formulated.

But if you have some long string somehow with the url embedded, you could do

```
text.split(/\shttp?s/).first
```

Comment: I use `client.status(id, tweet_mode: "extended")`. The extended payload has `full_text` it it. Here is more information: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/tweet-updates

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a quote Tweet where the original Tweet URL is included?

[edit - I was wrong with the above statement]

I see what is happening. The original Tweet links to an image on Twitter (`https://twitter.com/FloodSocial/status/994633657141813248/photo/1`, via a shortened tco link). Twitter hides the image URL in the rendered Tweet, but returns it in the body of the text. That's the expected behaviour in this case. You can also see the link parsed out in the `extended_entities` segment of the Tweet data, as well as the image data itself in the same area of the Tweet. If you want to omit the URL from the text data, you'll need to trim it yourself.

Comment: The original tweet does not have the URL in the text. The URL is added in the payload the `twitter` gem returns.